# Differential equation by a second order chemical reaction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $a\prime(t) = -2r[a(t)]^2$ and i want to find $a(t)$.

I have no idea how to solve, I tried to take integral on both side but this does not work and the answer was wrong, Can someone give me a hint where to start?

Comment: Assuming $r$ is not a function of $a$, use [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_(ODE))

$$a' = -2ra^{2} \implies \int \frac{da}{a^{2}} = \int -2r dt$$

Comment: @Mattos thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that we have 
$$\frac{da}{dt} = -2ra^2 \implies \frac{da}{a^2} = -2rdt$$
Now, we can take the integral of both sides to get:
$$\int\frac{1}{a^2}da = -2r\int dt$$
which yields 
$$-\frac{1}{a}+c = -2rt,\ c\in \mathbb{R} \implies a(t) = \frac{1}{2rt-c} $$

Comment: Why is there $c$ when we integrate $\frac{1}{a^2}$ not with $\int dt$?

Comment: Actually there are constants in both sides like $\frac{1}{a}+c_1 = -2rt+c_2$ but we can combine them by defining $c = c_1-c_2$ or $c = c_2-c_1$.

Comment: Thanks , it was confusing for me :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac{da}{dt}&=-2ra^2\\\frac{da}{a^2}&=-2r~dt\\\int\frac{da}{a^2}&=\int-2r~dt\\-\frac1a&=-2rt+c\\a&=\frac1{2rt-c}\end{align}$$ for some constant of integration $c$, to be obtained from initial conditions.

Comment: Should't be there a constant on one of the sides as well?

Comment: Yeah, i edited the answer.